# when i tried to link my post man and elasticsearch on logstash it gives me error?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

im just trying this for my project in class so i have no prior knowledge of elk stack

[image]

This is what i get when i run my .conf file

Elasticsearch - v8.10.2

Kibana - v8.10.2

Logstash-v8.10.0

My .conf file

```
input {
  http {
    host => "0.0.0.0"  # Listen on all network interfaces
    port => 9200      # Port to listen on (you can change this as needed)
  }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://localhost:9200"]  # Replace with your Elasticsearch server's address
    index => "testdb"          # Replace with your Elasticsearch index name
    ssl => true
    cacert => "C:\udownloads\elasticsearch-8.10.2\config\certs\http_ca.crt"
    ssl_certificate_verification => false
    user => "{MYUSER}"
    password => "{MYPASSWORD}"

  }
}
```

Edit:[My command Line Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ea7bk.png)

help is much appreciated...

I haven't tried anything since i couldn't find anything on this error

Comment: The error indicate that the issues is with your command line, the only thing you didn't include with your question.

Comment: my apologies i have added the command prompt 
@imotov

Comment: Nope, it looks like I was wrong and it is not the command line.

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue is that you setup an http input that is trying to listen on all interfaces on port 9200, but this port is already used by elasticsearch. To fix the issue just change the port your http input is listening on to something that will not clash with other running applications:

```
input {
  http {
    host => "0.0.0.0"  # Listen on all network interfaces
    port => 9201      # Port to listen on (you can change this as needed)
  }
}
```